# How to evaluate auto-encoder model for a single input?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have this auto-encoder model(using mnist dataset):

```
self.input = layers.Input(shape=(784,), name = 'input')#784 is flattened image, since 28*28
self.x = layers.Dense(h_dim, activation = 'relu', name = 'h1_enc',trainable=True)(self.input)
self.x = layers.Dense(e_dim, activation = 'relu', name = 'encoded', trainable=True)(self.x)    
self.x = layers.Dense(h_dim, activation = 'relu', name = 'h2_dec')(self.x)
self.output = layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid', name = 'out')(self.x)
self.model = Model(self.input, self.output)
self.model.compile(optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01), loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
```

I fit it like this:

```
self.model.fit(train_data, train_data, epochs = 20, batch_size = 16)#shape of train_data is (10000, 784)
```

and want to evaluate model like below for a single image from test_data:

```
self.model.evaluate(test_data[0], test_data[0])#test_data shape is (10000, 784)
#if I do as below
#self.model.evaluate(test_data, test_data)
# .evaluate works fine
```

but I get error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer h1_enc is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape (None, 1)
```

Comment: if test_data is numpy array, try in this way: model.evaluate(test_data[[0]], test_data[[0]])

Comment: You need to add the samples dimension (first dimension with a value of 1, to indicate that it is one sample).

Answer (score 0):

Reshaping the test data like below helped in solving the issue.

```
# Reshaping the test data
test_data= tf.reshape(test_data,(10000, 1, 784))
model.evaluate(test_data[0], test_data[0])
```

Output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 108ms/step - loss: 0.6935
0.6934699416160583
```

You can find the code [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/b147954e5e9356a2c42cafa1f340f233/untitled104.ipynb#scrollTo=SVpuUeMcHhHZ).